# How to position this CTA banner on top of two other divs without creating spacing?

Tags: css, frontend

Basically I want to implement a banner CTA block which would always go over the previous and next DIVs and NOT create a white empty spacing. I want to implement this in fluid way, irrespective of the height of the actual CTA banner block.

Code example: https://codepen.io/Gugols/pen/pORwxB

```css
.before-banner {
  background: pink;
  margin-bottom: -90px;
  min-height: 100px;
  padding-bottom: 90px;
}

.after-banner {
  
  background: orange;
  min-height: 100px;
  padding-top: 90px;
}
.cta-wrapper {
  /*min-height: 150px;*/

  margin-bottom: -90px;
}
.cta {
  width: 50%;
  background: green;
  opacity: 0.7;
  font-size: 28px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="before-banner paragraph">
  In consectetuer turpis ut velit. Sed consequat, leo eget bibendum sodales, augue velit cursus nunc, quis gravida magna mi a libero. Fusce a quam. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Cras non dolor.
    In consectetuer turpis ut velit. Sed consequat, leo eget bibendum sodales, augue velit cursus nunc, quis gravida magna mi a libero. Fusce a quam. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Cras non dolor.
    In consectetuer turpis ut velit. Sed consequat, leo eget bibendum sodales, augue velit cursus nunc, quis gravida magna mi a libero. Fusce a quam. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Cras non dolor.
    In consectetuer turpis ut velit. Sed consequat, leo eget bibendum sodales, augue velit cursus nunc, quis gravida magna mi a libero. Fusce a quam. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Cras non dolor.
    In consectetuer turpis ut velit. Sed consequat, leo eget bibendum sodales, augue velit cursus nunc, quis gravida magna mi a libero. Fusce a quam. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Cras non dolor.  In consectetuer turpis ut velit. Sed consequat, leo eget bibendum sodales, augue velit cursus nunc, quis gravida magna mi a libero. Fusce a quam. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Cras non dolor.
    In consectetuer turpis ut velit. Sed consequat, leo eget bibendum sodales, augue velit cursus nunc, quis gravida magna mi a libero. Fusce a quam. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Cras non dolor.
    In consectetuer turpis ut velit. Sed consequat, leo eget bibendum sodales, augue velit cursus nunc, quis gravida magna mi a libero. Fusce a quam. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Cras non dolor.
    In consectetuer turpis ut velit. Sed consequat, leo eget bibendum sodales, augue velit cursus nunc, quis gravida magna mi a libero. Fusce a quam. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Cras non dolor.
    In consectetuer turpis ut velit. Sed consequat, leo eget bibendum sodales, augue velit cursus nunc, quis gravida magna mi a libero. Fusce a quam. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Cras non dolor.
    In consectetuer turpis ut velit. Sed consequat, leo eget bibendum sodales, augue velit cursus nunc, quis gravida magna mi a libero. Fusce a quam. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Cras non dolor.
    In consectetuer turpis ut velit. Sed consequat, leo eget bibendum sodales, augue velit cursus nunc, quis gravida magna mi a libero. Fusce a quam. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Cras non dolor.
</div>
<div class="cta-wrapper">
  <div class="cta">
    <p>This is a CTA banner. Praesent egestas neque eu enim. Ut id nisl quis enim dignissim sagittis. Praesent vestibulum dapibus nibh. Etiam sit amet orci eget eros faucibus tincidunt. Vestibulum ante 
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="after-banner paragraph">
  In consectetuer turpis ut velit. Sed consequat, leo eget bibendum sodales, augue velit cursus nunc, quis gravida magna mi a libero. Fusce a quam. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Cras non dolor.
</div>
```

Some illustrations:

[image: The result I want to achieve]

[image: The result I get when the banner has bigger height]

Suggested CSS solution path would be ideal, but a JavaScript (jQuery as well) based one also could be acceptable.
Thank you.

Comment: Not sure how you expect anyone to help you with this when you haven't shown us any of your existing HTML, CSS or JS

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Good point. Will try to recreate it and post it here. Although it is a faulty implementation.

Comment: Showing the faulty implementation allows us to fix it - that is exactly what StackOverflow is for.

Comment: Ok, I have added the code implementation.

Comment: `position: absolute; transform: translateY(-50%);` can take care of positioning it in the middle between your two other elements - but because absolute positioning takes the element out of the flow, you would have to provide appropriate padding-bottom and -top to the other two elements, so that they reserve the space necessary - and it would need to be “enough” padding to keep enough space for different amounts of CTA content.

Comment: And you can’t use negative margins in percent, because even for top/bottom those are based on the _width_ of the element, not the height. Via JS you could easily measure the element height to use as a negative _pixel_ margin though; but if you need this to be “responsive” as well, you might need to add a resize handler that corrects the value if the viwport dimensions or orientation change ...

Comment: Thank you. It seems I will chose JS approach since I also couldn't think of any other CSS hackery which would work.

Comment: If that background image of the second section in your example was fixed to the viewport, then this could be done leaving the CTA wrapper element in normal flow - you would just give its upper half the background color of the previous section, and the lower one the fixed background image of the following. (The “halves” realized as absolutely positioned pseudo elements for example.) Since all content would be in-flow, there would be no trouble with providing spacing etc. either. But it will only work under these exact, limited conditions.

Answer (score 0):

The basic way to achieve an overlapping element (which doesn't create white space) is to set its `position` to `absolute`. To make it flow with the text in the element above, make this element contain the overlapping element with `position: relative`.

```css
.text-block {
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 50px;
}

.cta {
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  width: 50%;
  left: 25%;
}
```

```html
<div class="text-block">
  <p>basically I want to implement a banner CTA block which would always go over the previous and next DIVs but not create a white, empty spacing. I want to implement this in fluid way, irrespective of the height of the actual CTA banner block.</p>
  <div class="cta">basically I want to implement a banner CTA block which would always go over the previous and next DIVs but not create a white, empty spacing. I want to implement this in fluid way, irrespective of the height of the actual CTA banner block.</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Good hints. But it wouldn't work if there was a second text block (I have updated the question post with extra code). Also, the CTA due to the markup can't be inside another div (paragraph). It should be between.